# SpriteKit back to menu from SKScene

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am learning Swift & SpriteKit and currently facing one problem. Basically I am trying to implement clickable SKSpriteNode as "back to menu" and reset game.
My code so far:
in **GameScene.swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        //let node = self.nodes(at: location)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)

        if node.name == "back_button" {

            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuVC_ID")
            gameVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated:true, completion: nil)
            self.view?.presentScene(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuVC.swift**

```
class MenuVC : UIViewController {
    @IBAction func Player2(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: gameType.player2)
    }
    @IBAction func easy(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: gameType.easy)
    }
    @IBAction func medium(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: gameType.medium)

    }
    @IBAction func hard(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: gameType.hard)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print ("somtu")
    }
    func moveToGame(game: gameType) {
        print("movetogame")
        let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameVC") as! GameViewController
        currentGameType = game
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Whenever I click on `back_button` during game MenuVC is presented but then on button click nothing happens. I tried several suggestions from other posts but nothing worked properly.
Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite confused. If your project using the common structure:

> rootViewController-->rootView(SKView)-->scene(SKScene/MenuScene,GameScene,etc.)

you can switch scenes with `SKView.presentScene(SKScene, transition: SKTransition)`method and enable return functionality by passing parent scene variable to sub-scene or using `Notification` to trigger rootViewController present corresponding scene.

If your project wrapped each scene with view controller:

> MenuVC(MenuScene)-->GameVC(GameScene)

you can control app flow as normal app-

1. navigationController.push/navigationController.pop
2. viewController.present/viewController.presentingVC.dismiss
3. self.view?.window?.rootViewController = corresponding view controller

Comment: I changed self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true) to self.view.window?.rootViewController = gameVC and it's working like charm. Thank you